# how to change backgound color for an edittext if its input is filled or present?

Tags: android

I want to apply same yellow color background as their in second input box for the first input box where input is already given in-short how to give same input color when `editbox` is focused or input present here is my code i did it for if focused

[image]

Comment: do u need to change background color for only text is entered in edittext?

Comment: i want to change background when the 'edittext' is focused and if it has input in it else if empty means gray colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
before, int count) {
                   editetext.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
count,
                                              int after) {

 editetext.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   editetext.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
                }
            });
```

check for condition

```
    if(edittext.getText().toString()!=null)
    {
editetext.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
    }
else
{
editetext.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set background of your edit-text if value isn't equals to blank :

```
 ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               if(! ed.getText().toString().equals("")){

                  ed.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.color_yellow));

               }
            }
        });
```

You can add on text change listner link this !!

Comment: This answer is not enough, you need to show him when to run that code, in this case it is `textChangeListener`

Answer (score 0):

Add `addtextchangeistener` to your edit text and change the background/ tint in `onTextChanged` if there is input